# Properly passing my parameters in SSRS report on ASP.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm pretty close to figuring out an issue I've spent days on.

I'm trying to pass parameters to a SSRS report on an ASP.net page. The user selects 2 options on the page before, the program (drop down list of 3 programs) and the period (date).

I can get something to pass but not what I want. Here's the page where the user chooses what to display on the report:

```
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Alert", "alert('Bill Created!');window.open('../demographics/supbillrpt.aspx?prog=fprogram&period=cperiod','_self');", true);
```

fprogram is:

```
        SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter();
        param2 = command.Parameters.Add("@program", SqlDbType.Char);
        param2.Value = fprogram;
```

cperiod is the same thing but it is a date.

Here's the code behind on the page that displays the report:

```
        String sprogram = Request.QueryString[0];
        String speriod = Request.QueryString[1];

        ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
        ReportViewer1.Width = 800;
        ReportViewer1.Height = 600;
        IReportServerCredentials irsc = new CustomReportCredentials();
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = irsc;
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/sup_billing/Report1";
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
        ReportParameter p = new ReportParameter("prog", sprogram);                      ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { p });
        ReportParameter p2 = new ReportParameter("period", speriod); ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { p2 });
```

And what I get is the program being blank and the period says "cperiod"

I've tried a few different things to get it to read it as a variable but nothing seems to be working.

IF I put the following in:

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Alert", "alert('Bill Created!');window.open('../demographics/supbillrpt.aspx?prog=VEX&period=cperiod','_self');", true);

VEX is an item on that dropdown list and will show up because I put it there like that. But the user won't always select VEX so I need to use the fprogram variable. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm a little confused.  You say "fprogram is ..." and include a fragment of c#, which itself contains a reference to the variable `fprogram`?  What do you actually pass in the query string?

Comment: fprogram is a user selected item from a drop down list. Perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way. I want to pass that user selected parameter but here's the address part passing the paramater:      ('../demographics/supbillrpt.aspx?prog=fprogram&period=cperiod','_self')              So instead of grabbing the user selected parameter, it just reads "fprogram". I tried surround fprogram with single quotes and every syntax imagineable but i cant get it to pass as what the user selected

Comment: Sorry if I'm confusing you - I'm newer to this and have a hard time wording things so other programmers can understand it. To simplify it even more: User selects program, date period and then hits the "Bill Report" button. That should take them to the report page with those selected parameters. And I can't seem to get those selected parameters to pass through.

Comment: OK, I think I see what your problem is.  I'll write an answer and we'll see if it helps.

Comment: Will the code behind in my report page remain the same? The code you posted is just for the code behind on the Bill button, right?

Comment: Yes, it is.  The only thing that I might be concerned about in your code-behind in the report page is that you call SetParameters twice in a row.  Try setting it once and passing an array containing both parameters:  `SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { p, p2 })`.

Comment: Wow, that worked great. Thanks for your help. I did not know you could split up the ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript part like that. Do you mind me asking how long did it take you to become so proficient with C#/Asp.net??

Comment: Well ... I first used it in 2002, so I guess that's 11 years.  But some were more educational than others.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your first code fragment is the actual code you're using, rather than a mock-up of the general form of the code.  I am further assuming that you have variables called `fprogram` and `cperiod`.

You need to build your query string to reflect the exact values you wish to pass.  You cannot, unfortunately, code the name of the variable you want to use as the source of the value and have the actual value be inserted.

So your code should look something like this:

```
// I am assuming you're getting your fprogram and cperiod values from controls.  The 
// control names are of course up to you.

string fprogram = ddlProgram.SelectedValue;
string cperiod =  txtPeriod.Text;  // I'm assuming this contains a formatted date.

string queryString = String.Format(
     "../demographics/supbillrpt.aspx?prog={0}&period={1}", 
     fprogram, 
     cperiod);
string script = String.Format(
     "alert('Bill Created!');window.open('{0}','_self');",
     queryString);

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Alert", script, true);
```

Hope this helps.